# Can an iOS App be given permissions to edit/update/delete profiles?

Tags: ios, profile, enterprise, profiles

Can an app be given permission to edit/configure certain profiles that are tied to each other?

Comment: What profiles are you talking about?

Comment: Device profiles that affect proxy settings.

Comment: No, an app cannot change any profiles. You can share configuration between apps using an app group but nothing device wide